# How does calculation in a GRU layer take place

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

So I want to understand **exactly** how the outputs and hidden state of a GRU cell are calculated.

I obtained the pre-trained model from [here](https://github.com/nanoporetech/taiyaki) and the GRU layer has been defined as `nn.GRU(96, 96, bias=True)`.

I looked at the the [PyTorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) and confirmed the dimensions of the weights and bias as:

- `weight_ih_l0`: `(288, 96)`
- `weight_hh_l0`: `(288, 96)`
- `bias_ih_l0`: `(288)`
- `bias_hh_l0`: `(288)`

My input size and output size are `(1000, 8, 96)`. I understand that there are `1000` tensors, each of size `(8, 96)`. The hidden state is `(1, 8, 96)`, which is one tensor of size `(8, 96)`.

I have also printed the variable `batch_first` and found it to be `False`. This means that:

- Sequence length: `L=1000`
- Batch size: `B=8`
- Input size: `Hin=96`

Now going by the equations from the documentation, for the reset gate, I need to multiply the weight by the input `x`. But my weights are 2-dimensions and my input has three dimensions.

Here is what I've tried, I took the first `(8, 96)` matrix from my input and multiplied it with the transpose of my weight matrix:

```
Input (8, 96) x Weight (96, 288) = (8, 288)
```

Then I add the bias by replicating the `(288)` eight times to give `(8, 288)`. This would give the size of `r(t)` as `(8, 288)`. Similarly, `z(t)` would also be `(8, 288)`.

This `r(t)` is used in `n(t)`, since Hadamard product is used, both the matrices being multiplied have to be the same size that is `(8, 288)`. This implies that `n(t)` is also `(8, 288)`.

Finally, `h(t)` is the Hadamard produce and matrix addition, which would give the size of `h(t)` as `(8, 288)` which is **wrong**.

Where am I going wrong in this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR; This confusion comes from the fact that the weights of the layer are the concatenation of *input_hidden* and *hidden-hidden* respectively.**

---

##### - [`nn.GRU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) layer weight/bias layout

You can take a closer look at what's [inside the GRU layer](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L704) implementation [`torch.nn.GRU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) by peaking through the weights and biases.

```
>>> gru = nn.GRU(input_size=96, hidden_size=96, num_layers=1)
```

First the parameters of the GRU layer:

```
>>> gru._all_weights
[['weight_ih_l0', 'weight_hh_l0', 'bias_ih_l0', 'bias_hh_l0']]
```

You can look at `gru.state_dict()` to get the dictionary of weights of the layer.

We have two weights and two biases, `_ih` stands for '*input-hidden*' and `_hh` stands for '*hidden-hidden*'.

For more efficient computation the parameters have been concatenated together, as the documentation page clearly explains (`|` means concatenation). In this particular example `num_layers=1` and `k=0`:

- `~GRU.weight_ih_l[k]` – the learnable input-hidden weights of the layer `(W_ir | W_iz | W_in)`, of shape `(3*hidden_size, input_size)`.
- `~GRU.weight_hh_l[k]` – the learnable hidden-hidden weights of the layer `(W_hr | W_hz | W_hn)`, of shape `(3*hidden_size, hidden_size)`.
- `~GRU.bias_ih_l[k]` – the learnable input-hidden bias of the layer `(b_ir | b_iz | b_in)`, of shape `(3*hidden_size)`.
- `~GRU.bias_hh_l[k]` – the learnable hidden-hidden bias of the `(b_hr | b_hz | b_hn)`.

For further inspection we can get those split up with the following code:

```
>>> W_ih, W_hh, b_ih, b_hh = gru._flat_weights
>>> W_ir, W_iz, W_in = W_ih.split(H_in)
>>> W_hr, W_hz, W_hn = W_hh.split(H_in)
>>> b_ir, b_iz, b_in = b_ih.split(H_in)
>>> b_hr, b_hz, b_hn = b_hh.split(H_in)
```

Now we have the *12* tensor parameters sorted out.

---

#### - Expressions

The four expressions for a GRU layer: `r_t`, `z_t`, `n_t`, and `h_t`, are computed *at each timestep*.

The first operation is `r_t = σ(W_ir@x_t + b_ir + W_hr@h + b_hr)`. I used the `@` sign to designate the matrix multiplication operator ([`__matmul__`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)). Remember `W_ir` is shaped `(H_in=input_size, hidden_size)` while `x_t` contains the element at step `t` from the `x` sequence. Tensor `x_t = x[t]` is shaped as `(N=batch_size, H_in=input_size)`. At this point, it's simply a matrix multiplication between the input `x[t]` and the weight matrix. The resulting tensor `r` is shaped `(N, hidden_size=H_in)`:

```
>>> (x[t]@W_ir.T).shape
(8, 96)
```

The same is true for all other weight multiplication operations performed. As a result, you end up with an output tensor shaped `(N, H_out=hidden_size)`.

In the following expressions `h` is the tensor containing the hidden state of the previous step for each element in the batch, i.e. shaped `(N, hidden_size=H_out)`, since `num_layers=1`, *i.e.* there's a single hidden layer.

```
>>> r_t = torch.sigmoid(x[t]@W_ir.T + b_ir + h@W_hr.T + b_hr)
>>> r_t.shape
(8, 96)

>>> z_t = torch.sigmoid(x[t]@W_iz.T + b_iz + h@W_hz.T + b_hz)
>>> z_t.shape
(8, 96)
```

The output of the layer is the concatenation of the computed `h` tensors at
consecutive timesteps `t` (between `0` and `L-1`).

---

##### - Demonstration

Here is a minimal example of an `nn.GRU` inference manually computed:

| Parameters | Description | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `H_in` | feature size | `3` |
| `H_out` | hidden size | `2` |
| `L` | sequence length | `3` |
| `N` | batch size | `1` |
| `k` | number of layers | `1` |

Setup:

```
gru = nn.GRU(input_size=H_in, hidden_size=H_out, num_layers=k)
W_ih, W_hh, b_ih, b_hh = gru._flat_weights
W_ir, W_iz, W_in = W_ih.split(H_out)
W_hr, W_hz, W_hn = W_hh.split(H_out)
b_ir, b_iz, b_in = b_ih.split(H_out)
b_hr, b_hz, b_hn = b_hh.split(H_out)
```

Random input:

```
x = torch.rand(L, N, H_in)
```

Inference loop:

```
output = []
h = torch.zeros(1, N, H_out)
for t in range(L):
   r = torch.sigmoid(x[t]@W_ir.T + b_ir + h@W_hr.T + b_hr)
   z = torch.sigmoid(x[t]@W_iz.T + b_iz + h@W_hz.T + b_hz)
   n = torch.tanh(x[t]@W_in.T + b_in + r*(h@W_hn.T + b_hn))
   h = (1-z)*n + z*h
   output.append(h)
```

The final output is given by the stacking the tensors `h` at consecutive timesteps:

```
>>> torch.vstack(output)
tensor([[[0.1086, 0.0362]],

        [[0.2150, 0.0108]],

        [[0.3020, 0.0352]]], grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
```

In this case the output shape is `(L, N, H_out)`, *i.e.* `(3, 1, 2)`.

Which you can compare with `output, _ = gru(x)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination! I mistook the concatination operator `|` as 'or' and got really confused. I performed the calculations after splitting the weights and obtained `(1000, 8, 96)` .
While calculating `h_t = (1 - z_t) * n_t + z_t * h`, since `z_t` and `n_t` are `(1000, 8, 96)`, how does `h_t` end up being `(1, 8, 96)`. Is there something to do with timesteps?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, indeed the tensors are shaped `(1, 8, 96)` or (8, 96)` because each of those four expressions are computed at each timestep `t ∈ [0, L[`. Meaning we're using `x[t]` (not `x`) to compute `r_t`, `z_t`, `n_t`, and `h_t`. I have edited my answer and added the full implementation which should clear up the shape issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I did the calculations on my data using the loop as you have mentioned, and compared it with `output, _ = gru(x)` and both of them match. I just want to mention that there is a difference in some values 8 digits after the decimal point, but this is totally okay for my usecase. Thanks again!